# Can someone please provide an alternative to the "lsof" command

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm using `if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ;` and it worked fine on RHEL6 (4.82). But on RHEL5 (4.78) I'm seeing an error:

> lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: C lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI
> info selection: P lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: : lsof:
> unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: L lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info
> selection: I lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: S lsof:
> unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: T lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info
> selection: E lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: N lsof 4.78.

Can someone suggest an alternative to the above command?

I'm using this command to check the application status of servers with my assigned port numbers.

Comment: have you tried this -> http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/alternatives-for-lsof-command

Comment: By the way: support for RHEL5 ends in less than three months.

Comment: @ Carlos yes i tried but it didn't work for my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the PID and the port status.

```
netstat -pln | grep 9080
```

if you have multiple ports to check for, you could use this

```
for portnum in 9080 8080 8088 9082
do
     if [ $(netstat -pln 2>/dev/null | grep -c ${portnum}.*LISTEN) -eq 1 ]
     then
          echo "Port ${portnum} is up"
     else
          echo "Port ${portnum} is down"
     fi
done
```

you can ignore the "2>/dev/null" if you are running the command under root.

Comment: Thanks SudoAgent, is it possible to have out like for  abc up/down and cba up/down for portnumbers without portnumbers in output ?

Comment: Never mind i changed few things and its working as expected.. thanks